# Visual studio 2012 Ultimate missing Traits, projects,c lass on Test Explorer

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012, traits

I am using visual studio 2012 Ultimate version, on test explorer I am missing Traits/Projects/Class options...  [image: Missng Traits Projects Class on Test Explorer]

Am I missing something ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Updates the Visual Studio 2012 with latest -- Update 5

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48708